# SKPaymentTransaction originalTransaction behavior for subscriptions during restore is opposite of documentation?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, transactions, in-app-purchase, subscription

I'm a bit stumped by this.

When restoring transactions, I receive, as expected, an NSArray of all past transactions (as SKPaymentTransactions).  According to all documentation I can find on the internet, I should expect to see the SKPaymentTransaction's transactionDate property set to the time I did this restore.  If I want to see the date of when the subscription was originally made, I should be looking at the originalTransaction property's transactionDate.  I looked at several IAP guides and some stackoverflow posts, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328374/skpaymenttransaction-what-is-transactiondate-exactly).

In theory, my (incorrect?) understanding was:

transaction.transactionDate == Date of restore

transaction.originalTransaction.transactionDate == Date this particular subscription renewal was purchased

Is this correct?

Because what I am seeing, **when testing in Sandbox**, is the exact opposite.  I am seeing, in practice, the following:

transaction.transactionDate == The date the transaction was renewed
tarnsaction.originalTransactionDate == an older date, possibly the first time I ever purchased the subscription.

I've modified my code to work perfectly in the sandbox, but I'm concerned it will break in live if the sandbox is doing this wrong.   **I am using the transactionDate to determine when the subscription was purchased, and expiring 32 days later.**  If there's a better way to do this, I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: did this work for you?